# How to draw out normal distribution with Z score region marked on the graph?

Tags: r

For example, a normal distribution has mean=0,sd=1, and Z=-1.35, how to draw the graph out with this information in R?

Like, how to draw something like this :
[image]

Thanks,

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you want with `Z` but try

```
m <- 0; s <- 1; z <- -1.35
x <- seq(m - 5, m + 5, length = 1000)
y <- dnorm(x, mean = m, sd = s)
xx <- s * z + m
plot(x, y, type = "l", lwd = 1)
abline(v = xx, col = "red", lty = 2)
```

[image]